# SP Online search REST api calls return different results than the query builder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

Here's my api call to get news pages published on 2 sites in the last 60 days:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx AND PromotedState:2 Path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx Path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx FirstPublishedDate>{Today-60}'
```

This works correctly in the results sources query builder, but when tested in Postman the date restriction is ignored.

Also curious about how to add a rowlimit to the api call to only return the latest say 5 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append `&sortlist='FirstPublishedDate:descending'&startRow=0&rowlimit=5` to your request to sort response results and get the top five items.

You could know more about sharepoint search api here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Comment: Still returning out of scope results. Maybe I'm not getting the syntax right - you have a quote mark here after descending -- &sortlist= FirstPublishedDate:descending' -- was that a typo or closing  the "querytext"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 /_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx AND PromotedState:2  Path:https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx Path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx'&sortlist='FirstPublishedDate:descending'&startRow=0&rowlimit=5
```

Msft should provide a few more examples illustrating how to concatenate various components.

Comment: Yes,that is right.